# Copy and Paste Excel cells based on specific color

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with specific colors highlighting cells in random rows and columns. I would either a report of all Red, Orange, Green and yellow cells. Or I would like to copy each color cell and paste in  a specific column on another worksheet.

Please help.

Comment: I think you can solve your problem through filtering by color. Data -> Filter -> Filter by color

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the "Find" feature.

For example：Find out all the cells that are not red, locate them, and then delete them so that you can get all the red cells.

Next you can continue to get all green and other colored cells in this way。

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @user 4234-483244-34 stated, you can use the autofilter function to filter by color. However, this will only give you the red/green/whatever cells for a single column, so if you have lots of columns with random colors this will be tedious.

If you want anything more advanced, you will have to use VBA. For instance, you can make a user-defined function which returns the names of the specific colors you want, and then add a helper column with the names of all the colors in the row. Then you can filter on that column.